# asio strand post probabilistic non-response

Tags: c++, multithreading, asio

I wrote a simple test case about strand, but there is an unexpected phenomenon.

To put it simply, I constructed a thread pool with one io_context, and multiple strands. Then I tried to post multiple tasks to all strands, but probabilistically, some strands would not be responded to.

Let me show you the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include "asio.hpp"

// test case
int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}

// statistics
std::atomic<size_t> light_task_number_per_sec = 0;  // number of light tasks executed per second
std::atomic<size_t> heavy_task_number_per_sec = 0;  // number of heavy tasks executed per second
void statistics() {
    std::cout << "statistics, now: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() <<
        " light_task_number_per_sec: " << light_task_number_per_sec << " heavy_task_number_per_sec: " << heavy_task_number_per_sec << std::endl;
    light_task_number_per_sec = 0;
    heavy_task_number_per_sec = 0;
}

// config
size_t thread_number = 4;  // number of threads
size_t total_strand_number = 100;  // total number of strands
size_t heavy_strand_number = 2;  // number of strands to perform heavy tasks. NOTICE: heavy_strand_number should never be greater than thread_number, prevent all threads from getting stuck
size_t tasks_per_strand = 10000;  // The number of tasks posted per second per strand

int main() {
    std::cout << "ready to test, thread_number: " << thread_number << " total_strand_number: " << total_strand_number << " heavy_strand_number: " << heavy_strand_number << " tasks_per_strand: " << tasks_per_strand << std::endl;

    // make io and work
    auto uniq_io = std::make_unique<asio::io_context>();
    auto work = std::make_unique<asio::io_service::work>(*uniq_io);
    // make thread pool
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> thread_pool;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < thread_number; ++index) {
        thread_pool.emplace_back(std::make_unique<std::thread>(std::bind([io = uniq_io.get()]() { io->run(); })));
    }
    // make strand pool
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<asio::io_context::strand>> strand_pool;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < total_strand_number ; ++index) {
        strand_pool.emplace_back(std::make_unique<asio::io_context::strand>(*uniq_io));
    }

    // infinite loop for testing(post tasks to each strand)
    while (true) {
        for (size_t strand_index = 0; strand_index < total_strand_number ; ++strand_index) {
            for (size_t task_index = 0; task_index < tasks_per_strand ; ++task_index) {
                strand_pool[strand_index]->post([strand_index]() {
                    // some strands perform light tasks, and some strands perform heavy tasks
                    if (strand_index >= heavy_strand_number) {
                        fibonacci(10);  // light task
                        light_task_number_per_sec++;
                    }
                    else {
                        fibonacci(30);  // heavy task
                        heavy_task_number_per_sec++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        // sleep and statistics
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        statistics();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As shown in the code above, I created 4 threads, 100 strands, of which 98 strands perform light tasks and 2 strands perform heavy tasks. When heavy tasks accumulate, probabilistically, some of the 98 strands will not respond.

In my understanding, since only 2 strands will perform heavy tasks, so that at most 2 threads will be busy, and the remaining 2 threads will handle the light tasks posted by the remaining 98 strands.

Let me show my test results.
[image]

In theory, the number of light_task_number_per_sec should be 980000 (98 * 10000), but the result of the first test is only 960000, which is not expected (tasks in 2 strands are not executed), the results of the second test were as expected.

test environment is:

- asio version: 1.18.1
- Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) Debian 4.14.81.bm.15
- CPU Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8260 CPU @ 2.40GHz
- CPU(s): 8
- compile: g++ -I ./include/ asio_test.cpp -pthread -std=c++17 -O2 -o asio_test.out

Comment: How long do `fibonacci(10);` and `fibonacci(30);` take to execute? Note that all your heavy tasks will be posted to the front of the queue and will execute before the lighter ones

Comment: 980,000 light tasks (posted from 98 strands) take a short time, and 20,000 heavy tasks (posted from 2 strands) take a long time and cause accumulation. Also I'm pretty sure that only 2 of the 4 threads are fully loaded. In my understanding, each strand is completely independent, can you tell me why that "heavy tasks will be execute before the lighter ones". thanks a lot.

Comment: Tasks are executed in the order they're posted, I don't know the exact algorithm used in asio to select the next task for execution but i wouldn't be surprised if adding 20,000 tasks in the front of the queue prevents other tasks from running

Comment: I found the reason (updated in the question). Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: You should post an answer rather than editing the answer into the question

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I will edit it again.

Answer (score 1):

After an in-depth investigation, it was found that
[image]

The allocation algorithm of strand adopts the hash by default, this will cause part of the strand to actually be merged,
but the user is unaware of this.

For example in my test case, I tried creating 100 strands, but in fact there are only more than 70 truly independent strands, the rest of the strands are actually reused.

If a strand that posts light tasks is unlucky enough to be merged into a strand that posts heavy tasks, unexpected results can occur.